# Add Xom to managed URI In res

Tags: jrules, ibm-odm

I am Working on ILOG.Currently I am using an Ant script for deploying ruleapp to res.My Problem is when I am deploying it is working fine but I want to add xom automatically to " ADD Managed URI" tab present in res. xom is getting attached to ruleapp but i want to get it attached to managed uri section.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what you tried, such as which version of IBM JRules/ODM you are working with, which ant task are you calling with what arguments... What do you actually mean by the _"xom is getting attached to ruleapp"_: XOMs are attached to **ruleset** through managed URIs

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this way - Got it from IBM Help.I have not tried it, but looks like, it should work. ( IBM ODM.8.0.1)

```
<target name="deployruleappwithxom">
    <res-deploy hostname="${hostname}" portnumber="${portnumber}" webapp="${webapp}" userid="${userid}" password="${password}" file="my-ruleapp.jar">
        <xompath rulesetpath="/MyRuleApp/MyRuleset">
          <fileset dir="${lib}">
              <include name="**/myxom.jar" />
          </fileset>
        </xompath>
        <xompath rulesetpath="/AnotherRuleApp/AnotherRuleset">
          <fileset dir="${otherlib}">
              <include name="**/otherxom.jar" />
          </fileset>
        </xompath>
    </res-deploy>
</target>
```

if you just looking for managing xomuri property, you can try this.

```
<target name="runloanvalidation">
    <res-deploy-xom
        hostname="localhost"
        portnumber="9080"
        webapp="res"
        userid="resAdmin"
        password="resAdmin"
        jarMajorVersion="false"
        libName="person"
        outputRulesetProperty="ruleset.managedxom.uris">
        <xompath>
        <fileset dir="hello">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        </xompath>
    </res-deploy-xom>
    <echo message="Resulting property: ${ruleset.managedxom.uris}"/>
</target>
```

And for more information, you can visit this.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSQP76_8.6.0/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.ref.res/ant_tasks/con_ant_res_deploy_xom.html

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the **res-deploy-xom** ANT task. And if  your actual deployment mode is either _File System_ or _Database_ I think you **have to** use res-write-xom-file or res-write-xom-db. See [Ant tasks for Java XOM management](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r5m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.ref.res%2Fant_tasks%2Ftpc_ant_tasks_jxom_intro.html) and [Ant tasks for RuleApp management](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmanager/v8r5m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.ref.res%2Fant_tasks%2Ftpc_ant_tasks_ruleapps_intro.html) - ODM 8.5.1 doc

Comment: this is not working out.Can someone tell where to change property of "managedxom.uris"

Comment: Please let us know what you tried and what error you got?

Comment: I have tried this  <target name="runloanvalidation">
    <res-deploy-xom
        hostname="localhost"
        portnumber="9080"
        webapp="res"
        userid="resAdmin"
        password="resAdmin"
        jarMajorVersion="false"
        libName="person"
        outputRulesetProperty="ruleset.managedxom.uris">
        <xompath>
        <fileset dir="hello">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        </xompath>
    </res-deploy-xom>
    <echo message="Resulting property: ${ruleset.managedxom.uris}"/>
</target>

Comment: Can someone help as how and where to declare value of "ruleset.managedxom.uris"

Comment: Wherer have you kept jar file - path - the same dir structure needs to be followed in fileset  dir tag

Comment: ya i have used same path structure

Comment: Ankit...it's ruleset property and you have to assign it at ruleset level within your ruleapp. Refer to this post: [Deploy Classic Ruleset without XOM](https://odm4rules.wordpress.com/2015/09/25/deploy-classic-ruleset-without-xom/)